# How to stop content keeping in line in embedded table-cell in CSS?

Tags: css, css-tables

I want to use the `table-cell` to make a two-col layout. the content in the inner table has no relationship with the outer table.

My problem is the `menu` in the `left-col` will keep in line with the content in the `inner-` table-cell(the `inner-left-head` and `inner-right-head`). How can I stop it?

```css
.wrap {border: 1px solid #ddd;}

.left-col,
.right-col
{
    display:table-cell;
}

.left-col {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  width:17.5%;
  max-width:209px;
}
.right-col {width:2000px;}

.right-col-main { 
  margin: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.inner-left-col,
.inner-right-col {
  display: table-cell;
  height:300px;
}
.inner-left-col {
  width:100px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.inner-right-col {
  width: 500px;
}

.inner-left-head,
.inner-right-head {
    height:48px;
    line-height:48px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"> 
<div class="left-col">
        <dl>
            <dt>menu<dt>
            <dd>sub1<dd>
            <dd>sub2<dd>
            <dd>sub3<dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">
        <div class="right-col-main">
            <div class="inner-left-col">
                <div class="inner-left-head">left head</div>
                <div class="inner-left-body">left body</div>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-right-col">
                <div class="inner-right-head">right head</div>
                <div class="inner-right-body">right body</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried use `table-row` to wrap the `table-cell` but I can't see any difference.

Comment: post your css that will help solving

Comment: ^ that, please. And preferably as a runnable snippet (using the HTML/CSS/JS Snippet button in your question editor).

Comment: i feel bad for div's when they are abused in this fashion and made to act like tables :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for editing. It's starting to become clear now. You want to be able to scroll the right column while keeping the left column in sight. Then my question is, why did you make this table layout?

I think you're looking for `position: fixed` to fixate the left column to the top left corner. You can position the right column by just giving it a left margin.

So the styling for the left and right columns becomes:

```
.left-col {
  position: fixed;
  width: 17.5%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.right-col
{
  margin-left: 17.5%; /* Same or larger as width of left colum */
  height: 2000px; /* Force some height to see the effect.
}
```

```css
.wrap {border: 1px solid #ddd;}

.left-col {
  position: fixed;
  width: 17.5%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.right-col
{
  margin-left: 17.5%; /* Same or larger as width of left colum */
  height: 2000px; /* Force some height to see the effect.
}

.right-col-main { 
  margin: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.inner-left-col,
.inner-right-col {
  display: table-cell;
  height:300px;
}
.inner-left-col {
  width:100px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.inner-right-col {
  width: 500px;
}

.inner-left-head,
.inner-right-head {
    height:48px;
    line-height:48px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"> 
<div class="left-col">
        <dl>
            <dt>menu<dt>
            <dd>sub1<dd>
            <dd>sub2<dd>
            <dd>sub3<dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">
        <div class="right-col-main">
            <div class="inner-left-col">
                <div class="inner-left-head">left head</div>
                <div class="inner-left-body">left body</div>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-right-col">
                <div class="inner-right-head">right head</div>
                <div class="inner-right-body">right body</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. No, I don't want a fixed left column. I would like to let the left col scroll with the right col. What I really want is the left col "fixed" when I change the position of the content in the right. For example, you can see I set `line-height` to the right content, which makes the `left head` and `right head` moves downward a little, and the `menu` text moves too.

Comment: I know the content will keep in line with `table-cell`, but in my case there's two different `table`. I want to know if can I stop them keeping in line. If there's no way, I will consider the `fixed` layout :)

Comment: If you don't want fixed and you don't want them in line with each other, then what other options are there? You could make each cell 100% of the height, and make it scrollable. That way, you got a separate scrollbar for each of the sides.

Comment: I don't think here is the "scroll" problem(there's no scrolling in this page in fact). The problem is the texts' position. If you try to change the line-height of the "left" and "right head", you could see the "menu" moves together. Because the table-cell makes them keep in line even they are in different table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using table-cells you could use floats. Combined with relative width settings you will furthermore have a more responsive solution.

This is just one example how it could be working:

```
.left-col,
.right-col {
    float:left;
}

.left-col {
  background:#abc;
  width:17.5%;
}

.right-col {
    background:#aed;
    width:82.5%;
}

.right-col-main { 
  margin-top:40px;
}

.inner-left-col,
.inner-right-col {
  float:left;
}
.inner-left-col {
  width:20%;

}
.inner-right-col {
  width:80%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xn0zuo7h/

Comment: I tried the float layout. The problem here is the height of the left and right column is unsure. This may cause some unexpected problem with the `border-right`

Comment: Which kind of unexpected problem?

Comment: the border' will follow the float content's actual height. But what I need is a fix height line.

Comment: You could still add the border directly to the element with fixed height within the floating div.

Comment: I might have misread your question. I thought left-col and right-col are not related instead of left-col and inner- cols. A limitation of the floating divs is their height has no relation.